# Typescript import aliases not working in dist

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

My aliases are not working, looks like the compiler is not transpiling @utils to $path/utils.

I have the following structure:

```
src
├── server
│   └── resolvers
│        └── mutations
│             └── user.mutation.ts -> import { encryptPassword } from "@utils/auth.js" 
└── utils
    └── auth.ts

dist
├── server
│   └── resolvers
│       └── mutations
│            └── user.mutation.js -> import { encryptPassword } from "@utils/auth.js" (expected to be path-to-dist-utils/auth.js)
└── utils
    └── auth.js
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDirs": [
      "src"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting TS to interpret aliases correctly, but for some reason the aliases are being registered, but not well read by the dist js.

Answer (score 0):

typescript just uses this alias path to parse its type system, and doesn't actually change the reference path of a JavaScript file, which is done using other methods or libraries, such as `tsc-alias`